# Is it possible to set up (geographic) anycast on the Internet?

Tags: multicast, dns, anycast

The top level DNS-servers use geographic anycast. Is it possible to set up geographic anycast on your own (DNS) servers on the Internet?  The top level DNS-servers use geographic anycast. Is this set up in the routing tables in all internet "nodes"? Is it possible to implement anycast to do geographic load balancing?

For instance, if you own an IP-address, you can set up for example nginx on this server to do load balancing on a local server farm. Then nginx does all the communication with the client. However, what if you want to have multiple data centers located around the world? I want to set up servers at multiple locations to minimize latency.

You can also set up a DNS-server returning IPs based on the requester's location. This would enable geographic load balancing. However, what happens if this DNS-server is slowed down because of much traffic? Is it possible to load balance these DNS servers?

Comment: You should look at global traffic load-balancing appliances from vendors like Cisco or F5, if you have any kind of budget.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  But you would have to advertise a /24 network (or larger), based on current Internet routing policies.  So if your name server IP was 1.2.3.4, you would have to advertise 1.2.3.0/24 from each of your locations.  The rest of the addresses in that subnet would be, practically speaking, wasted.  You also would have to have your own provider-independent address space, which is not easy to come by, especially on IPv4.

Comment: Does this mean that all nodes in the backbone of the internet would have to set up the anycast in their routing tables? I suppose this is done automatically some way or another?

Comment: when you advertise a network (technically called a prefix) with BGP, all the backbone routers will learn it.  If you advertise from more than one location, each router will choose one location based on either routing policy or shortest distance (AS path).